# Remove duplicate item from multidimensional array

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array, duplicates

How would I go about removing duplicate items from my multidimensional object array?

In my sample below, I have 2 items which contain the `id` value of `4` (`fullname is 'Jodie (Y6Y5)'`).

I need to modify my array so that there are no duplicate `id` values.

I've tried doing loops to fix it, and I've also tried `array_unique()`.

Does anyone have any better ideas on how I can achieve this?

Example input array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 4
            [pupil_id] => 1
            [pupil_id_1] => 2
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Jodie (Y6Y5)
            [email] => jodie@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => 
            [telephone] => 0777777777777
            [telephone_2] => 07777777777
            [username] => jerrys
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-06 14:23:02
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:18:08
            [login] => 2018-02-13 15:45:09
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 86
        )

    [1] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 3
            [pupil_id] => 5
            [pupil_id_1] => 2
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Karla (Rec Y5)
            [email] => karla@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => ally@email.com
            [telephone] => 
            [telephone_2] => 
            [username] => rickygutpa
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-06 10:33:30
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:16:21
            [login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 86
        )

    [2] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 1
            [pupil_id] => 4
            [pupil_id_1] => 0
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Florence (Y6 2)
            [email] => florence@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => 
            [telephone] => 0777777777777
            [telephone_2] => 
            [username] => mrslacey
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-01 09:47:34
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:49:32
            [login] => 2018-02-05 11:48:54
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 87
        )

    [3] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 4
            [pupil_id] => 1
            [pupil_id_1] => 2
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Jodie (Y6Y5)
            [email] => jodie@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => 
            [telephone] => 0777777777777
            [telephone_2] => 07777777777
            [username] => jerrys
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-06 14:23:02
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:18:08
            [login] => 2018-02-13 15:45:09
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 87
        )

)
```

Expect Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 4
            [pupil_id] => 1
            [pupil_id_1] => 2
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Jodie (Y6Y5)
            [email] => jodie@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => 
            [telephone] => 0777777777777
            [telephone_2] => 07777777777
            [username] => jerrys
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-06 14:23:02
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:18:08
            [login] => 2018-02-13 15:45:09
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 86
        )

    [1] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 3
            [pupil_id] => 5
            [pupil_id_1] => 2
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Karla (Rec Y5)
            [email] => karla@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => ally@email.com
            [telephone] => 
            [telephone_2] => 
            [username] => rickygutpa
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-06 10:33:30
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:16:21
            [login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 86
        )

    [2] => guardian Object
        (
            [guardians] => Array
                (
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

            [id] => 1
            [pupil_id] => 4
            [pupil_id_1] => 0
            [pupil_id_2] => 0
            [pupil_id_3] => 0
            [pupil_id_4] => 0
            [school_id] => 1
            [title] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [surname] => 
            [fullname] => Florence (Y6 2)
            [email] => florence@email.co.uk
            [email_2] => 
            [telephone] => 0777777777777
            [telephone_2] => 
            [username] => mrslacey
            [password] => password
            [active] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [inserted] => 2018-02-01 09:47:34
            [updated] => 2018-02-14 14:49:32
            [login] => 2018-02-05 11:48:54
            [last_login] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_app] => 0
            [email_update_app_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [email_update_web] => 0
            [email_update_web_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [is_wonde] => 0
            [wonde_id] => 
            [wonde_mis_id] => 
            [wonde_upi] => 
            [grade_id] => 87
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice (and a technique that you will find implemented in Stackoverflow questions every day) is to assign temporary keys, overwrite any pre-existing subarrays based on the temporary keys, then remove the temporary keys at the end.

This avoids having to do iterated lookups.  For highest efficiency in your codes, try to minimize iterated function calls.

Method #1: Remove earlier duplicate occurrences / Retain last occurrences ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rccdh))

```
foreach($guardian->guardians as $subarray){
    $result[$subarray->id]=$subarray;  // assign temporary keys
}
$guardian->guardians=array_values($result);  // re-declare and remove temporary keys (re-index the subarrays)
var_export($guardian);
```

*Alternatively, here is a functional-style one-liner providing the same effect: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EFcDq))

```
$guardian->guardians=array_values(array_column((array)$guardian->guardians,NULL,'id'));
var_export($guardian);
```

For those who don't know, `array_column()` chokes on objects, so objects must be temporarily converted to arrays.

---

Method #2: Remove later duplicate occurrences / Retain first occurrences ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/68Osv))

```
foreach($guardian->guardians as $subarray){
    if(!isset($result[$subarray->id])){
        $result[$subarray->id]=$subarray;  // only store if first occurrence of id
    }
}
$guardian->guardians=array_values($result);  // re-index
var_export($guardian);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a working answer by doing as following:

```
$tempGuardians = array();

foreach($guardian->guardians as $key => $value){
    if (in_array($value->id, $tempGuardians)){
        unset($guardian->guardians[$key]);
    } else {
        array_push($tempGuardians, $value->id);
    }
}

unset($tempGuardians);
```

If anyone knows any cleaner ways or better ways of doing this, I'm open to new ways.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is included on your question, you already said it: array_unique:

```
$newArray=array_unique($a1);
```

Comment: This would only work if I had two arrays right? I'm not working with two arrays

Comment: I've tried the `array_unique` it doesn't work on multidimensional arrays